# verificar se tabela temporaria existe mysql

Tags: mysql, procedure

Ola gostaria de saber se é possivel como seria feito para verificar se uma tabela temporaria existe antes de cria-la. O que tentei é `IF (SELECT COUNT(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'molar' AND table_name = 'tmp_horario_livre') = 0 THEN CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_HORARIO_LIVRE( ID INT, DATA_INICIO DATETIME, DATA_FIM DATETIME ); ALTER TABLE` TMP_HORARIO_LIVRE `ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`); ALTER TABLE` TMP_HORARIO_LIVRE`MODIFY`ID `int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5; END IF;`

isso por que pretendo fazer um loop na proc pai para inserir registros varias vezes na mesma tabela.

Estou fazendo assim pq aparentemente o mysql não permite criar tabelas antes de qualquer declare de variavel ou cursor

Answer (score -1):

Daria para dropar caso exista e criá-la:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table_name;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table_name(id int);
```